# How can I get a matrix table from two related table by one query statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How can I get a matrix table from two related table by one query statement like the picture shows? or do I have to use a temporary table instead?

Comment: thank you very much, it's very great to know how to query with dynamic columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for this, note that the solution is for the current data structure, if there are more roles in the role table then its not a proper solution. Since the inner query will needs to be changed to accommodate new roles.

```
select 
id,
name,
coalesce(max(t.FW),'No') as FW,
coalesce(max(t.DF),'No') as DF,
coalesce(max(t.GK),'No') as GK,
coalesce(max(t.MF),'No') as MF
from user u
left join (
  select 
  case 
    when r.id = 1 AND ur.role_id is not null then 'Yes'
    else null
  end `FW`,

  case 
    when r.id = 2 AND ur.role_id is not null then 'Yes'
    else null 
  end `DF`,

  case 
    when r.id = 3 AND ur.role_id is not null then 'Yes'
    else null
  end `GK`,

  case 
    when r.id = 4 AND ur.role_id is not null then 'Yes'
    else null
  end `MF`,
  user_id
  from role r
  left join user_role ur on ur.role_id = r.id
)t
on t.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```

I added `No` for null values , this could be changed in the statements like

`coalesce(max(t.FW),'No') as FW,`

So instead of No can just add `' '`

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8beb7/11)**

Comment: Though this solution is not able to add columns automatically(have to add manually), it is very simple and is what I expected. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a CROSS JOIN between the user and role tables to get every possible combination, and LEFT JOIN the User_Role table to get matches where one exists.

This would give one returned row per user / role combination. This could then be output easily in a table in whatever language you are using.

```
SELECT User.id AS user_id, User.name, Role.role, IF(User_Role.role_id IS NULL, NULL, 'yes')
FROM User
CROSS JOIN Role
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Role
ON User.id = User_Role.user_id
AND Role.id = User_Role.role_id
ORDER BY User.id, Role.id
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, it's good to learn how to use CROSS JOIN, and I think the result can be used as a temporary table.